# How to open a specific view controller from a command to Siri?

Tags: ios, swift, shortcut, siri

For example:
if I give command to Siri "Show me my purchase history in [MyApp]"
action should be a segue to that particular view controller in my app.

I have designed an app named CodeX (A handy compiler), I want to add Siri support in version 2 with above capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

SiriKit currently is limited to specific category of service (known as a domain), like fitness, messaging, and payments and can perform certain actions related to these domains only. Your app can integrate with Siri if your action fits in the current supported [Domains and Intents](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sirikit/overview/domains-and-intents/). I don't think you can perform the segue since it's not a directly supported action.